# How to find character array length in Android

Tags: java, arrays, char

I had used the following code to find the length

```
String str=strLenData.toString();
int ipLen= str.length();
return ipLen;
```

`ipLen` would return 11 every time. whatever be the actual value of `strLenData`. when I call toString() function, value of `str`: "*[C@40523f80*". Now I have to use char[] and i need to know the end (or length) of char[].

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you show the code that construct strLenData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly the `strLenData` variable is a char[]? In that case, you can just do

`return strLenData.length;`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `strLenData` is charSequence or something. its just a regular object and may be it does't have **toString()** method. so `toString()` method of **Object** class gets called which just returns the `HashCode` value of The Objects Reference.

so make sure `strLenData.toString()` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

ipLen is returning 11 always because you are converting an char array to String equivalent by using toString() method.
if you want to create String by an char array use.
String str = new String(strLenData);

Or if you want just want to get length of your char array use answer given by Steven.
use strLenData.length;